# I am not a Feminist or I wouldn't tolerate you people

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, negation

1. "I am not a Feminist or I wouldn't tolerate you people."

I read this in the captions of a movie trailer and I found it hard to understand. There are two negative words and the use of the word *or.*

Does "I am not a Feminist or I wouldn't tolerate you people" mean "I am not a Feminist; if I was I wouldn't tolerate you people"?

Would either of these be considered better?

2. "If I were a Feminist I wouldn't tolerate you people."
3. "I am not a Feminist or else I wouldn't tolerate you people."

Is the original sentence considered good English?

Comment: There is no "double negative"--there is one negative for each clause.

Comment: "It's not anything like that I'm a feminist or (that) I wouldn't tolerate you  people." "I'm not a feminist and I can tolerate you people." "Or else I wouldn't tolerate you people if I were a feminst." There are many ways to say and mean the same thing as 1, 2, and 3. Whichever you say, I can tolerate you.

Comment: It's a good thing I'm not a feminist because if I were I wouldn't be able to tolerate you people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first guess (***1.***) is right. The clearest way to paraphrase the caption is probably:

> I am not a feminist: because if I were a feminist, I wouldn't tolerate you people.

2) Is good grammatical English, but it misses out the clear assertion in the original that, 'I am not a feminist'.

3) Is also clear, common and acceptable in colloquial speech. It wouldn't be appropriate in every [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)), though, because it's ambiguous between: 'EITHER I'm not a feminist OR I wouldn't tolerate you people' (**logical disjunction**: which is semantically strange here, but grammatically OK); and 'I'm not a feminist, OTHERWISE I wouldn't...' (**subjunctive**).

As to whether the original is 'good English'? **NO**. The '***or***' in the original sentence can be seen as a synonym for '*or else*' or '*otherwise*'. Because the word *or* is so common and has so many uses, this usage can be confusing. So, if 'good English' implies stylish, educated, logically clear, unambiguous... the original caption is a *fail*.

BUT:

i) *In a film caption/subtitle, terseness can trump style. So the original might have been a great choice of words* *in situ*.

ii) *I always try to give references for my answers, but I don't know where to begin on this one... suggestions, anyone?*